# Cannot remove prior installation of package, but package not found

Tags: r, windows, installation

I have been installing packages into R since the day I downloaded it. Version 3.4.1. Today it gave me an issue when I tried to install a new package, `SLOPE` that had me update and reboot R. I said okay. However, in doing so I then went to call packages using the `library` and it told me:

```
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘plyr’ in loadNamespace(j
> <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):  there
> is no package called ‘Rcpp’
```

I have clicked around on here and it looks like I need to download and install the `Rccp` package. I tried that and got this answer:

> > install.packages("Rcpp") Installing package into ‘\tgdcfs01/Users/jsmith/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’ (as ‘lib’ is
> >     unspecified) trying URL
> >     'https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2017-09-01/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/Rcpp_0.12.12.zip'
> >     Content type 'application/zip' length 3319164 bytes (3.2 MB)
> >     downloaded 3.2 MB
>
> package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked Warning in
>   install.packages :   cannot remove prior installation of package
>   ‘Rcpp’
>
> The downloaded binary packages are in
>     C:\Users\jsmith\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpYHBW2f\downloaded_packages

So then I tried uninstalling `Rccp` and got this message:

```
 remove.packages(Rcpp)
Error in remove.packages : object 'Rcpp' not found
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Should it be `remove.packages("Rcpp")`?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try `'Rcpp'`. R is looking for an object called Rcpp, a variable in your environment. Also, there seems to be some confusion with the lib paths. If you type `.libPaths()`, R will show you all the possible locations of installed packages... that may provide some additional clues

Comment: Okay so I have 2 file paths when I call `.libPaths()` One is on my C drive and the other is listed above as the tgdcfs01.... None of them have the Rcpp package installed. The C drive is not writable. The other drive states package `Rcpp` successfully unpacked, but warning in install.packages: cannot remove prior installation of package `Rcpp`. Then it states the downloaded binary packages are in a Temp folder in downloaded_packages on my C Drive.

Comment: Try restarting R. On Windows, updating packages if they've already been loaded can cause problems and I suspect that may be happening here. Start R, look at `sessionInfo()` and make sure Rcpp isn't loaded. Then try `remove.packages("Rcpp")` and `install.packages("Rcpp")` in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix it, I in fact did not update R in the first place. I needed to do the following:

```
install.packages("installr")
library(installr)
updateR()
```

Then I updated R, but I did not use the recommended setting of using R Gui. Then I was able to re-install packages and go from there.